# DigitalExperienceManager-CommunityDistribution-7.3.1.0 starts with error 'Cannot set maven executable to mvn, please check your configuration'

Tags: jahia

I've installed DigitalExperienceManager-CommunityDistribution-7.3.1.0-r59490.jar on my MAC, and run the commands to start it:

```
cd /Applications/DigitalExperienceManager-CommunityDistribution-7.3.1.0/
./start.sh
```

I find this error in catalina.out:

> 2020-12-16 19:14:55,509: INFO  [ProcessHelper] - [mvn, -version]
> 2020-12-16 19:14:55,517: ERROR [ModuleBuildHelper] - Cannot set maven
> executable to mvn, please check your configuration
> org.jahia.exceptions.JahiaRuntimeException: java.io.IOException:
> Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or
> directory     at
> org.jahia.utils.ProcessHelper.execute(ProcessHelper.java:203)     at
> org.jahia.utils.ProcessHelper.execute(ProcessHelper.java:138)     at
> org.jahia.services.templates.ModuleBuildHelper.checkMavenExecutable(ModuleBuildHelper.java:493)
> at
> org.jahia.services.templates.ModuleBuildHelper.afterPropertiesSet(ModuleBuildHelper.java:534)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)

> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
> at
> org.apache.pluto.driver.PortalStartupListener.contextInitialized(PortalStartupListener.java:108)
> at
> org.jahia.bin.listeners.JahiaContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(JahiaContextLoaderListener.java:235)

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory
> "."): error=2, No such file or directory  at
> java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
> java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)  at
> org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:61)
> at
> org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:279)
> at
> org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:336)
> at
> org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
> at org.jahia.utils.ProcessHelper.execute(ProcessHelper.java:199)    ...
> 80 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or
> directory     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)     at
> java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:247)    at
> java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)     at
> java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)  ... 86 more
> 2020-12-16 19:14:55,523: ERROR [ModuleBuildHelper] - Until maven
> executable is correctly set, the studio will not be available

But I'm sure maven is installed on my machine already:

> $ mvn -version Apache Maven 3.6.3
> (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f) Maven home:
> /Users/george/apache-maven-3.6.3 Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor:
> Oracle Corporation, runtime:
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
> Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "mac os x",
> version: "10.15.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have maven in your path? Seems Jahia cannot find maven on startup. When it is not in path you can specify in jahia.properties (\digital-factory-config\jahia\jahia.properties) the full path to maven:

```
#mvnPath = mvn
```

Uncomment this property and specify the right path to maven like:

```
mvnPath = /usr/local/apache-maven/bin/mvn
```

Comment: Thanks. I've moved maven installation from ~/apache-maven-3.6.3 to /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3, and re-exported /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin, then the application started correctly.